# Displaying Another Screen Onclick in Android

Tags: android

```
package com.example.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {         
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }     
        });
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors however my program also dont run as I want. I am new in android and I want to change the screen after the button is clicked for that I am using two classes so in one class my program should invoke another one onclick. How can I do this ? My code is as above.

Comment: You're calling `setContentView()` twice, I'm quite sure you shouldn't be doing that. As far as I know, you should call it as the first one in `onCreate()`, and only once.

Answer (score 3):

First remove `this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` because you declared it twice . Then declare

`btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);`

after

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

**Declare your profile activity in manifest file.Check my code below.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) your oncreate method should look like below one.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }     
    });
```

2) Add **profile** Activity into Manifest.

3) add logs in onClick method so you should know if it is getting called on not.

Happy coding!!